# Reshape nearby polygons so that they share a common border

Tags: polygon, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm for reshaping polygons that are close to each other.

Given 2 polygons that have certain parts within proximity E reshape the polygons such that they share a common border within the area of proximity.

Example input:

```
        Q1   Q2
        +-----+  
P1  P2  |     |
+----+  |     |
|    |  |     |
|    |  + Q5  |
|    |   \    |
+----+    +---+
P4  P3    Q4 Q3
```

Example output:

```
         Q1  Q2
         +----+  
P1  P2Q /     |
+------+      |
|      |      |
|      + Q5P  |
|     / \     |
+----+   `+---+
P4  P3    Q4 Q3
```

As for what I tried: some Googling and thinking. I suppose I have a rough (untested) idea how I could do that but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: which API do you have at your disposal? arcpy integrate https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000 and snap https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000 are fairly close to what you're after if you have Esri objects available, GeometrySnapper https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#snap-geometries-to-layer in QGIS might help, the algorithm should be available from the source https://github.com/qgis/QGIS

Comment: I don't have anything specific. So open source application or ideally small library in some language would be best.